# validates_presence_of and unsaved associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

Take the following code (Rails 3.0.10):

```
User < AR
  has_many :providers

Provider < AR
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user

user = User.new
user.providers.build
# so both models not yet saved but associated with each other

user.valid?
=> false

user.errors
=> {:providers=>["is invalid"]}

user.providers.first.errors
=> {:user_id=>["can't be blank"]}
```

Why can't Provider see that it has a not yet saved associated user model available? Or in other words - how can I deal with that so that the validation is still present? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Note, that I'm looking for a clean solution, so suggesting a before validation callback in Provider model saving the User model to the database is a no-go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use :inverse_of

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :providers, :inverse_of => :user
end

class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :providers
  validates :user, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: *is a bad idea in Rails* -- any proof?

Comment: A lot of experience. The fact that the OP's code doesn't work, etc.

Comment: "Bad idea"... pfff. It's basically the same deal as with nested attributes - do you consider them to be a bad idea as well? Anyway long story short, it's for Omniauth and for Twitter to be exact. I can't roll it in transaction because this happens between requests -- since Twitter does not provide emails I don't want to save empty User record. So I need to build both models first and save only if they are both valid. Oh, and it's not me doing the .save call. Devise does that.

Comment: OK. There's an alternative solution for you.